# how to use an image created by pillow library as input in neural network

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, python-imaging-library

I have a function that creates an image object from scratch using the PIL library. I want to use this image as an input to neural network **without having to save the image and load it again**

the following code creates an image with a rectangle in it

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img_size = 300
image = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(img_size, img_size), color=0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.rectangle([(50, 50), (250, 250)], fill=255, outline=255, width=1)
image.show()
```

How would one go about using this object 'image' as in input to any neural network?
tensorflow and pytorch both are fine, I just need something that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can pass `PIL` image to `torch` model
If `image` is your `PIL <Image> class`
Then

```
from torchvision import transforms
pil_to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()(image).unsqueeze_(0)
output = model(pil_to_tensor ) #
```